# How to resize a html background picture inside body tag

Tags: html, css, image, background, content-management-system

I want a background image (bg.png) in my html, but I want resize that image,so it'll fill always the whole page. I did it like this:

```
.stretch {
width:100%;
height:100%;}

#background {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -1; }
```

Inside of the body:

```
<div id="background">
<img src="bg.png" class="stretch">  
</div>
```

So I am using a CMS (e107) on the website now, and I want the background like in my html, I changed the picture but I don't know how to use this in that css/php file.

This is it in the theme's css:

```
body 
{
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
width: 87%;
border-color: #39393b;
border-width: 0px;
border-style: solid;
color: #C0C0C0;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #444440;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(images/bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

How can I add that stretch inside to this css?

Comment: You can use a background-size: cover; on your body to set the bg.png on the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you're looking for

```
body { 
    background: url('images/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: note that `background-size` property is compatible with IE9+, although for IE8 the Mozilla Doc says "it is possible to emulate some of its functionality using the non-standard -ms-filter function", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size